# Sveltekit couldn't load and render data from Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, svelte, sveltekit

I've been trying to get this sveltekit code to work for the past 1 week and no matter how I tried, it doesn't seem to work.

Before I go to my code, this is the error message:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length') TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
    at Proxy.each (/Users/cadellteng/Documents/code/police/APDVolunteers/node_modules/svelte/internal/index.js:1710:31)
    at eval (/src/lib/components/officer-list.svelte:74:29)
    at eval (/src/lib/components/officer-list.svelte:109:5)
    at officer-list.svelte:45:12
    at Object.$$render (/Users/cadellteng/Documents/code/police/APDVolunteers/node_modules/svelte/internal/index.js:1745:22)
    at eval (/src/lib/sections/training-record.svelte:25:94)
    at Object.$$render (/Users/cadellteng/Documents/code/police/APDVolunteers/node_modules/svelte/internal/index.js:1745:22)
    at eval (/src/routes/admin/index.svelte:17:97)
    at Object.$$render (/Users/cadellteng/Documents/code/police/APDVolunteers/node_modules/svelte/internal/index.js:1745:22)
    at Object.default (root.svelte:43:39)
```

This is my code to get data from Firebase:

```
<script lang="ts" context="module">
    // Import Firebase
    import { db } from '$lib/scripts/firebaseInit'; //from my custom FirebaseInit.ts
    import { collection, getDocs } from 'firebase/firestore';

    export async function load() {
        let allOfficers = [];
        console.log("Loading data");
        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "officers"));
        // console.log(querySnapshot);
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
            let data = doc.data();
            // console.log(doc.id, " => ", data);
            allOfficers.push(data);
        });
        console.log(allOfficers)
        return {
            props: { allOfficers }
        };
    }
</script>

<script lang="ts">
    export let allOfficers;
</script>
```

And the following are my code to render the data:

```
<div class="officer__list">
    {#each allOfficers as officer}
        <div class="officer__card accordion">
            <div class="officer__content-details">
                <h4 class="officer-name">{officer.name.displayed}</h4>
                <p class="officer-rank-appointment">
                    Rank 1 | Head of Department
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    {/each}
</div>
```

And just in case you are wondering if my `FirebaseInit.ts` is not working well, I have another example that worked without changing anything in the script tags:

```
<div class="test-container">
    <ul>
        {#each allOfficers as officer}
            <li>
                {officer.name.displayed}
            </li>
        {/each}
    </ul>
</div>
```

The above works like magic without changing anything in the script tags.

Edit: This is a component within a bigger svelte file. I realize when I make this its own route, it works...? What's wrong?

Comment: The ` export async function load() {` is only run for routes. When using firebase inside nested components you'll need to manage the loading (and empty state) yourself

Answer (score 0):

So I have managed to solve the problem and I can't use the context module to load data at the component level. After I move the script tag content for the load to the route level, it works perfectly. I just need to pass it down into individual components as props.